# Date format for variable

Tags: bash, date, variable

I need to write a variable with "date" function and I need that the format is yyyymmdd (i.e. 20151031). Also I would remove a day (i.e. 20151031 becomes 20151030)
I would use bash.

Thanks!

Comment: see `man date`. the `date` command allows you to format the output

Comment: `man date` , and yesterday is: epoch - 86400  (seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `date +%Y%m%d` to print the current date.
Use `date --date '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d` to print yesterday's date (GNU's `date`).
Use `date -v -1d +Y%m%d` (FreeBSD).

Comment: Ok, but if I put it into a variable I get error

#!/usr/bin/env bash
DATE=date --date '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d
gunzip -c /var/log/cisco/cisco.log-echo $DATE.gz > /var/log/cisco/file.log

root@raspberrypi:/etc/my_scripts# date --date
date: option '--date' requires an argument

Comment: You have to enclose your command into `$()`. Example : `DATE=$(date --date '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)`

Answer (score 2):

bash-4.2 and above have built-in support for that (inspired from something similar in ksh93):

```
printf -v now '%(%s)T' -1
printf '%(%Y%m%d)T\n' "$((now - 86400))"
```

Would print yesterday's date (well, the date 86400 seconds ago) in YYYYMMDD format. It may not work if run at certain hours of the night at the time of winter/summer time switch (when days are 23 or 25 hours long).

It would probably be more reliable for those corner cases if written as:

```
printf -v now '%(%s:%H)T' -1
printf '%(%Y%m%d)T\n' "$((${now%:*} - 3600 * (12 + ${now#*:})))"
```